# Why does quantize() not use the full color palette?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a big `RGBA` image generated using Pillow.

When saving the file using

```
img.save(f"{name}.png", optimize=True)
```

it results in a 10.4 MB file with 319 different colors.

Now, when I save the file using

```
img.quantize(colors=256).save(f"{name}.png", optimize=True)
```

I expect the resulting image to have 256 different colors. But, it actually only has 171. It also has 5.4 MB.

Why does `quantize()` not use the full color palette?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here seems to be the `RGBA` mode of your input, cf. the [source code of `Image.quantize`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/PIL/Image.html#Image.quantize):

```
By default, :data:`MEDIANCUT` will be used.

The exception to this is RGBA images. :data:`MEDIANCUT` and
:data:`MAXCOVERAGE` do not support RGBA images, so
:data:`FASTOCTREE` is used by default instead.
```

A small toy example using this image

[image: Example image]

shows the difference:

```py
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('DCIVc.png')

print(len(img.quantize(colors=256).getcolors(maxcolors=2**24)))
# 256

print(len(img.convert('RGBA').quantize(colors=256).getcolors(maxcolors=2**24)))
# 144
```

You could try the [`LIBIMAGEQUANT`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html?highlight=quantize#PIL.Image.LIBIMAGEQUANT) method, but therefore, [you'd need a custom built version of Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/releasenotes/3.3.0.html#libimagequant-support), and a proper installation of `libimagequant` itself. On the other hand: Do you explicitly need the `RGBA` mode, i.e. the transparency information? If not, simply switch to `RGB` mode.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.19042-SP0
Python:        3.9.6
PyCharm:       2021.2
Pillow:        8.3.1
----------------------------------------
```